# Different translations for multi-tenant applications

Tags: php, laravel, localization, multi-tenant

I'm developing a multi-tenant application where I'm using the same codebase for two different websites, each available in two languages.

- Website A FR
- Website A EN
- Website B FR
- Website B EN

Laravel allows you to store the localization translations in the `resources/lang` directory, under a different folder for each language (in this case one `fr` folder and one `en` folder).

This works well, but there are some strings that need to be translated differently depending on the current tenant. On website A, the "Home" button link might be called "Home" and on website B it would be called "Go to Home".

How can I specify different translations files for different tenants?

I tried doing something like this :

```
/ ressources
  / lang
    / fr
      / tenantA
        - messages.php
      / tenantB
        - messages.php
    /en
      /tenantA
        - messages.php
      /tenantB
         - messages.php
```

Then, I set the locale globally in a service provider :

```
App::setLocale('en');
```

I then try to load the proper translation from my view :

```
{{ __('tenantA.messages.home') }}
```

This does not work however, it only echo's out `tenantA.messages.home` (the literal string) instead of the translation that is contained in the `messages.php` file, under the `home` key.

How can I fix this? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work with `sub-directories` using `.` but it'll work with a `/`, so for example, you may try it the following way (tested on `v-5.4`):

```
{{ __('tenantA/messages.home') }}
```